# Opening a file in write mode

Tags: bash, file, shell

I have a file called a.txt. with values like

```
1
2
3
...
```

I want to overwrite this file but

```
echo "$var" >> a.txt
echo "$var1" >> a.txt
echo "$var2" >> a.txt
...
```

just appends. Using > is not useful as well. How can i overwrite with using >> operator in shell script?

Comment: Can you be more specific about why "using > is not useful"? Doesn't it overwrite, precisely as you request?

Comment: echo "$var" > a.txt
echo "$var1" > a.txt
echo "$var2" > a.txt when i use this the file has only $var.

Comment: echo "$var" > a.txt should do the job try that

Comment: so perhaps you want `echo "$var" > a.txt echo "$var1" >> a.txt echo "$var2" >> a.txt`  (that is, erase the file just the first time, then append the others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use `>` for the first redirection and `>>` for subsequent redirections:

```
echo "$var" > a.txt
echo "$var1" >> a.txt
echo "$var2" >> a.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

`>` truncates the file if it exists, and would do what you originally asked.

`>>` appends to the file if it exists.

If you want to overwrite the content of a file (not truncate it), use `1<>`

e.g.:

```
[23:58:27 0 ~/tmp] $ echo foobar >a
[23:58:28 0 ~/tmp] $ cat a
foobar
[23:58:50 0 ~/tmp] $ echo -n bar 1<>a
[23:58:53 0 ~/tmp] $ cat a
barbar
```

Answer (score 2):

In what way is using > not useful? That explicitly does what you want by overwriting the file, so use > for the first and then >> to append future values.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "$var
$var1
$var2" > a.txt
```

or

```
echo -e "$var\n$var1\n$var2" > a.txt
```